# Alternatives to using a SQL UNION in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a friends table with columns user1 and user2 and a users table with a login field.

A friend "pair" can be stored either way, for example user1=Joe and user2=Dave, or it could be user1=Dave and user2=Joe, same thing.

I want to find all friends of a user (say "Joe") that have been logged in within the last 30 days (I'm not concerned about the date format, just want to be able to do it in 1 query).

Is using a UNION the only solution, does it have the best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union is not the only option, you can for example do like this:

```
select u.user
from users u
inner join friends f on u.user = case f.user1 when 'Joe' then f.user2 else f.user1 end
where f.user1 = 'Joe' or f.user2 = 'Joe'
```

Whether that is faster than a union depends on several things, mostly on what indexes you have.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` isn't necessary here. Just select `where user1='Joe' OR user2='Joe'`

Comment: Although presumably you also need some sort of case statement in the select to pull out the appropriate user column as the "friend".